# DQL OneToMany query and performing average

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

In a `OneToMany` relationship between the entities:

- `Composer` > `Soundtrack`
- `Soundtrack` > `SoundtrackRating`

i want to select each `Soundtrack` by a given `Composer` and avergage the `SoundtrackRatings` for each `Soundtrack`.

In `DQL`:

```
SELECT s.name, (SUM(r.rating)/COUNT(r.rating)) AS rating 
FROM Soundtrack AS s 
LEFT JOIN SoundtrackRating AS r 
WHERE s.composer = :composer AND r.soundtrackId = s.id 
GROUP BY s.id 
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Then i'm passing the `:composer` instance of type `Composer`:

```
$em->createQuery($dql)
  ->setParameter('composer', $composer)
  ->getResult();
```

However in the query result i am getting all `Soundtrack` entries, no matter what `$composer` i pass as a parameter. The only difference is that only averages the ratings of the given `$composer`, the rest averages `0`.

Where is the problem in this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Removing `r.soundtrackId = s.id` from the `WHERE` clause and using `WITH` in the `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT s.name, (SUM(r.rating)/COUNT(r.rating)) AS rating 
FROM Soundtrack AS s 
LEFT JOIN SoundtrackRating AS r WITH r.soundtrackId = s.id
WHERE s.composer = :composer 
GROUP BY s.id 
ORDER BY rating DESC
```